# Solving a Bernoulli equation with power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Let $y(x)$ be a solution for the initial value problem for the Bernoulli equation $$y'=y^2-x,\ \ \ y(0)=1.$$
I want to find $a_n$ for $n\leq5$ in the sequence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$.

So I know that $$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_n x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1} x^n$$
but I have no clue how to get any further from here... Any tips?

Comment: Do you know how to square a series? You can just do it by hand for the first few terms $$(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots)^2=a_0^2+2a_0a_1 x+(a_1^2+2a_0a_2) x^2+\dots$$ now substitute this and the derivative into the equation. From $y(0)=1$ you already know that $a_0=1$, which simplifies the expressions

Comment: Thanks! Just to check, I get $a_0$=1 and from there on I get $a_i=0$ for $1\leq i \leq 5$.

Comment: No, at least from what I see. Do the substitution and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a [Bernoulli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_equation) but a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). There is a transformation to a second order linear ODE that makes computing power series solutions easy, which give rational expressions for this equation that can also be expanded as power series.

Set $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ then
$$
0=y'-y^2+x=-\frac{u''}u+x
$$
so you have to solve the Airy equation
$$
u''(x)=xu(x)
$$ 
with $u(0)=-1$, $u'(0)=1$.
Apart from expressing the solution via [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function), the power series $u=\sum a_kx^k$ satisfies
$$
a_0=-1\\
a_1=1\\
a_2=0\\
(k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}=a_{k-1}~\text{ for }~ k\ge 1\\
a_3=-\frac16\\
a_4=\frac1{12}\\
a_5=0,\dots
$$